# Is there a POSIX implementation where sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(off_t)?

Tags: c, posix

I think that it would be rather odd if sizes of in-memory object should be allowed to be bigger than on-disk objects, but I guess that there's nothing in the standard that prohibits this.

The question is if there's an implementation that this is true? Note the strict difference - there's (plenty) of cases where sizeof(size_t)=sizeof(off_t).

Comment: It's tricky to get answers to a question like that.  If there is one and someone who knows about it happens to spot the question and deigns to answer, you're home and dry.  But in the absence of such an observation by an informed person, you'll never know whether the right person hasn't read the question or there really isn't such a system.  I know of no such system, but I don't know every POSIX system out there in the world by a long shot.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, of course. If there's only negative answers they will probably only considered a subset of all POSIX systems and one can not be sure about that. As always with question whether something exists one would have to settle with the assumption that it doesn't until some proof or indication otherwise.

Comment: Not sure about POSIX, but 16-bit systems would normally have 16-bit size_t and 32-bit fpos_t.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Even non-POSIX systems that use `size_t` and `off_t` sanely that have `sizeof(size_t)` > `sizeof(off_t)` would be an indication that ther might be POSIX systems to. Note though that 16-bit `size_t` and 32-bit `fpos_t` is no such example.

Comment: It’s possible to compile source with `-DFILE_OFFSET_BITS=32 -m64`, but I don’t know if GCC and libc will honor that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there? No, almost certainly not, especially if you only count certified implementations. I would guess (this is something of an educated guess based not on having seen the code, but on having seen lots of places where POSIX was implicitly assuming characteristics similar to historical implementations) the certification test suite would even fail to run on systems significantly different from "expected" behavior.

Could there be? Perhaps. If you need a type that suffices for storing either, just use `uintmax_t` rather than encoding assumptions about the relationship between them.

Comment: `uintmax_t` would however not be guaranteed to be able to store `off_t` unchanged (since `uintmax_t` is unsigned while `off_t` is signed).

Comment: @skyking: If you only care about storing file *positions* and not signed offsets for relative seeks, it's certainly fine.